# How to create NSArray of unique key form objects NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, nsarray

I have an NSArray of objects:

```
class Object {
    var name: String? = nil
    var id: String? = nil
}
```

I want to create an NSArray of unique 'name' value. Normally in Objective-C I would use:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"];
```

but there is no method 'valueForKeyPath' in swift. How can I do this in swift?

Comment: you can use like this: var max = (numbers as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("@max.self") as Double hope this will help you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to do that - at least, I don't know any.

An algorithm to achieve that is to use a dictionary to keep track of unique names, and taking advantage of 'filter' and 'map':

```
var dict = [String : Bool]()

let filtered = array.filter { (element: Object) -> Bool in
    if let name = element.name {
        if dict[name] == nil {
            dict[element.name!] = true
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

let names = filtered.map { $0.name!}
```

`dict` stores names already processed as key, and a boolean as value (which is ignored).
I use `filter` to produce an array of `Object` elements where the `name` property is unique, i.e. discarding all subsequent instances if the `name` property is found in the dictionary.

Once the array of elements with unique name is obtained, I use `map` to transform the array of `Object`s into an array of `String`, taking the `name` property from each `Object` instance.

If you're going to reuse this method in several places, it's a good idea to add it as an extension method to the `Array` type.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the power of NSArray, just make sure your `Object` extends `NSObject`:

```
class Object:NSObject {
    var name: String? = nil
    var id: String? = nil
}

let originalArray = [Object(), Object()]
let array = NSArray(array: originalArray)
let result = array.valueForKeyPath("@distinctUnionOfObjects.name") as [String?]
```